# WSO2 ESB High Availability

Tags: wso2, esb, high-availability

How is High Availability achieved with WSO2 ESB clustering .

Suppose there are 2 nodes clustered and there is a load balancer , what happens when a node which is handling few HTTP requests goes down , what will happen to the requests ? will they be lost or because of the clustering the pending requests will be moved to the other node in the cluster.

What needs to be done to achieve this . Can you please suggest ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HA will handle by the load balancer, not by the ESB.Basically if esb node failure happens load balancer or the invoking client should handle that situation. If LB and client haven't implemented to handle such a failure scenario, there will be a message loss.LB has to route new requests to the other available node.

WSO2 recommend using Nginx as the default load balancer.ESB clustering documentation can be found on [cluster doc](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Clustering+ESB+4.9.0).

Comment: Thanks for the response , in that case what is the WSO2 ESB clustering(Hazelcast) doing either master-worker or worker -worker setup doing for high availability.

Comment: Hazelcast uses for internal cluster communications like cluster node coordination,artifact synchronization, distributed cache management,....etc

Comment: Can we say that WSO2 clustering has nothing to do for HA ?  if you have LB and also no clustering between the nodes it is the same wrt to HA

Comment: No,We can't say like that. Different WSO2 products use WSO2 clustering(HZ) for different purposes as i mention above.Basically to support HA both nodes should be in the same state. In ESB HZ clustering using  for cluster coordination which is used by features like inbound, tasks, MSMP.

Comment: yes i agree with what you say , can you share list of features that use HZ cluster to sync the ESB nodes. based on these features if we are not using the features we can take a call on the HZ clustering to do or not. My requirement is mainly wrt WSO2 ESB